# Select Range of cells based on Row Number on a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely lost. I am trying to use values from cells on a different sheet to establish the Starting Row and the Ending Row, in ColumnA of the Active Sheet.

I keep getting Compile Errors. Can someone help with the VBA format?

```
Dim s As String
s = "=Math!A3"
Range("=Math!C3", 1)("=Math!D3", 1) = s
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some variables:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Math")
    Dim startRow As Long
    startRow = .Range("C3").Value

    Dim endRow As Long
    endRow = .Range("D3").Value
End With

Dim s As String
s = "=Math!A3"

ActiveSheet.Range("A" & startRow & ":A" & endRow).Formula = s
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I get a 'Subscript out of range'  error running your code. On the first line. Can you provide any context on why?

Comment: That means the workbook containing this code has no worksheet named _Math_.

Comment: That would have been my guess... but it definitely does have a sheet named Math.

Comment: Maybe there's a trailing space on the end of Math.

Comment: With the 'ThisWorkbook'... does it matter that I am using PERSONAL.XLSB and not the workbook xlsx for the code?

Just trying to use Google to figure out the error.

Comment: Yes. Change `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: You, Sir, are a superhero.